# Execution plan changes when using hard-coded date vs. using variable date

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-execution-plan

This query:

```
select * from mytable where mytable.somedate = '08 Sep 2015'
```

Produces a different execution plan to this query:

```
-- (people from the future - assume today is 08 Sep 2015)
select * from mytable where mytable.somedate = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

Which isn't a problem in this tiny example query, but as part of a much larger query there's a very, very large performance hit. The version of the query with a `where mytable.somedate = '08 Sep 2015'` takes under a second, the version with a `where mytable.somedate = dateadd(...)` takes *over 30 seconds*, due to only this change.

The type of `somedate` is `datetime`, and is indexed. I tried putting `dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)` into a variable, and I've tried various datetime casts on both sides of the clause. I've also tried different ways of getting today's date without a timestamp (eg `cast(getdate() as date)`). All produce the slow execution plan - it appears only a hardcoded date produces the fast plan. A hardcoded date can't be used, as the query needs to return records for *today*, whatever day *today* is.

How can I make this run quickly?

Comment: Does the *actual* problematic version involve parameters? Or involve row data? or... i.e. is it actually involving `some_column` or `@some_param` in the computation?

Comment: The actual version is a 700-line monolith of a query (I didn't write it!), but the final where clause is the same as listed in the question: `somedate = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)`. That runs in 30+ seconds. Changing it to `somedate = '08 Sep 2015'` runs in < 1 second. (note due to the sensitivity of the data I work with, I've substituted the actual table / column names, but `somecolumn` is indeed an indexed datetime column coming straight out of a table)

Comment: and to be clear: you're saying it doesn't work if you do `declare @date datetime = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0);` ... `mytable.somedate = @date;` ? how about if you add `option (optimize for (@date unknown));` ?

Comment: Is `somedate` stored as `dd mon yyyy`?

Comment: question: what is the data type of `somedate` ? `date` ? or `datetime`? or ... ?

Comment: @Samcd: No, it's a `datetime`, not a text type.

Comment: @MarcGravell: "The type of `somedate` is `datetime`"

Comment: @MarcGravell Tried both of those, no dice. `somedate` is an indexed datetime and cannot be null

Comment: @Kai if it is indexed: have you tried an explicit index hint?

Answer (score 0):

As the DateAdd is based on GetDate() and not a column Date, try

```
Declare @Date
SELECT @Date = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)
Select * from mytable where mytable.somedate = @Date
```

Comment: Can you post the two execution plans ?

Answer (score 0):

I get this may be more of a comment but give it a try
If it does not work then I will just delete

It might be query optimizer being conservative and going into a loop join
Can you bring the condition up into a join

e.g.

```
select *  
  from main 
  join date 
    on date.ID = main.ID 
 where date.somedate = @somedate
```

to

```
select *  
  from main 
  join date 
    on date.ID = main.ID 
   and date.somedate = @somedate
```

even if date is in the main

```
select *  
  from main 
  join otherTable
    on otherTable.ID = main.ID 
   and main.somedate = @somedate
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats with the crazy DateTime conversion?

Cant you just do

```
select * from mytable where mytable.somedate = CAST(getdate() AS DATE)
```

I don't have enough test data to see if this is any quicker but i do this sort of thing all the time at work. However i would normal have a local called @Now that has been set to the result of GETDATE and then used in the proc.  By the name of your 'somedate' column, this should just be a DATE type and not a DATETIME. For best results always try and match the comparison data types exactly this would help the index out.

If it really needs to be a DATETIME Then you can cast the DATE back to a DATETIME  eg  CAST(CAST(getdate() AS DATE) AS DATETIME) DO NOT CAST the somedate column down to a DATE in the proc as you will loose the full power of the index.

I also know for a FACT that using a literal is not the same as using a variable with a constant value.

So

```
WHERE A = 'Something'
```

IS NOT THE SAME AS

```
DECLARE @B NVARCHAR(n) = 'Something'
WHERE A = @B
```

Same result but NOT the same code. (don't ask me why) I would **guess** that the compiler is never sure if a local is truly constant so it cant optimist it out.